# Horizontal centering of a fixed div when the height not fixed

Tags: html, css

How do I center a fixed div when the height not fixed?

```
.centerDiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50px;
}

<div id="div1" style="height:300px;width:120px;background-color:red;right:10%;" class="centerDiv"></div>
<div id="div2" style="height:500px;width:120px;background-color:red;right:50%;" class="centerDiv"></div>
```

Example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qCLit

How do I always have a div in the center?

Answer (score 0):

Might be other legit ways but this is gonna give you the most freedom.

Contain the `div` you want to be centered inside of another `div`.  The container div will be the fixed one but it'll be transparent (just there to hold the floaters).  Then you can set your inner `centerDiv`s to `position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 120px;` as usual.

Example below, [fiddle can be seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/h7f2S/).

HTML:

```
<div id="contain">
    <div id="div1" style="height:300px;background-color:red;" class="centerDiv"></div>
    <div id="div2" style="height:500px;background-color:red;" class="centerDiv"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#contain {
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.centerDiv {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 120px;
}
```

It's not entirely clear what your goal is with the other div(s) around the centered one so if you elaborate I can adjust to fit your situation better.  Right now they both just center on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center horizontally a fixed element with the width fixed:

```
.centerDiv {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: -150px; /* width/2 */
}
```

The same apply to center vertically (with height set):

```
.centerDiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: -150px; /* height/2 */
}
```

To center horizontally a div with dynamic width, you will have to add another div, and use the inline-block to the child div:

```
<div class="outerCenterDiv">
  <div class="centerDiv">test</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outerCenterDiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center
}
.centerDiv {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

To center vertically a div with dynamic height, you will have to add another div, and play with the inline-block style and line-height:

```
<div class="outerCenterDiv">
  <div class="centerDiv">test</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outerCenterDiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 100%;
}
.centerDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.4; /* reset the line-height to your good value */
}
```

And you can combine both solutions.